# Error Missing file part Php Google cloud platform POST

Tags: php, html

I'm simply trying to "post" text from a subscribe form to a simple email php file but Google Cloud gives this error:

```html
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Invalid argument.</Message>
<Details>Missing file part</Details>
</Error>
```

I have tried a few things including writing directly to the bucket in Google Cloud but I would rather have text emailed to an address. Why is there a missing file part?

here is my form code:

```html
<form action="email.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="email" size="15" style="font-size:29px;" id="email" required placeholder="Email">
<input value="RSVP" class="button" name="button" style="font-size:29px;" type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my php file:

```html
<?php

$to = "email@gmail.com"; // 
$from = "no-reply@website.com"; // 

$headers = "From: " . $from . "rn";

$subject = "New subscription";
$body = "New user subscription: " . $_POST['email'];
if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
{
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from))
{
echo 'Your e-mail (' . $_POST['echo $this->mail'] . ') has been added to our mailing list!';
}
else
{
echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: _“Why is there a missing file part?”_ - can only guess here with the info you have given, but - probably because you used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form …? That is what you _need_ to set for a file upload, but it sounds like you didn’t intend to perform any in the first place here. _Because of_ that enctype being set, the API probably assumes you were trying to perform an actual file upload, and now wonders why there isn’t any file data contained in the request.